# Can I erase previous page content before above-page slide in?

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui

I create my project with `ons-sliding-menu` of Onsen UI. When I click a menu item in behind-page, above-page slide in, but still show the previous content for one second (very short time, but you will notice that).

Can I erase previous page content before above-page slide in?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you post any code that you tried this far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the above page to new content, first the browser needs sometime to fetch and render the new content, resulting in some delay.

On modern device and browser, this happens so fast that you don't notice it. But in older devices, you may notice the delay.

Could you provide your device info eg. OS version, browser...?

Comment: iPhone 5.Can I add some code to erase content first ?

Comment: You can modify the source code https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/master/framework/directives/sliding_menu.js#L95

Put the line before setTimeout();

If you use Monaca, you need to un-check Onsen UI in plugins loader and upload your edited file. Or copy the onsenui.js file in plugins folder to your own www folder and modify it there.